# How to forecast a series (daily power consumption) with multiple seasonalities?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality, multiple-seasonalities

I wish to forecast electricity power demand at a mall. Data is collected daily, but, the data has multiple seasonality :

1. data/power consumption is generally similar from monday to thursday but see a change on friday, saturday, sunday (weekly seasonality) ?
2. power consumption vary with month. Summer months the power consumption is higher due to cooling required ?
3. Year on year there is increase in power consumption with deployment of more equipments. (Yearly seasonality) ?

Series contain only date and power consumption (daily data). What seasonality should I use ?

Option 1:

```
powerts <- ts(data,start=2016,frequency=7) 
modArima <- auto.arima(powerts)
```

Option 2:

```
powerts <- ts(data,start=2016,frequency=365) 
modArima <- auto.arima(powerts)
```

But both seems lagging as they fail to cover all the three points above

Comment: Click on the [tag:multiple-seasonalities] tag. Click on "Learn more". You will arrive at [the tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-seasonalities/info), which contains pointers to literature and R packages.

Comment: Also check out https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/